# Entity Framework 4.2 Release - Where is DbGeography/Spatial?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

The code I have inherited is using the three Entity Framework installers from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

It has now been flagged that these three are CTP releases and are not going to be suitable going forward in development.

I have seen there has been a new release of the entity framework here: http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.2.0.0/Download

So I de-installed all of the CTPs and downloaded this and the compile fails because of missing `DbGeography` and `Spatial`

So where are these available from? If they are not available in none CTP code then what are there alternatives available to handle their functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere. [EF 4.2 doesn't contain them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/01/ef-4-2-released.aspx). Features from CTP "should" be included in .NET 4.5.

Comment: From looking into it further I was afraid this might be the case which now appears means we need to revisit the EF code that has been done. Maybe there is something that can be done with what we have or maybe it would be more sensible at this stage to stop using EF altogether, in which case is there an alternative framework that has the same capabilities?

Comment: I'm not aware of any ORM natively supporting SQL Server spatial data.